# Angular POST service

Tags: angular, api, servicio

Tengo una API que recibe por Header un parámetro Acción que se le puede pasar Borrar/Agregar/Eliminar y por Boody un objeto.

Este código implemente en Angular y si por alguna razón que no me doy cuenta, no le llega el objeto a la api.

**Componente:**

```
(La Api fue probada por postman y funciona)

      delBeneficios(){
    let token = localStorage.getItem('currentUserToken');
    console.log(token);
    this._enjoyCommunityService.delBeneficios(this.beneficioSelected).subscribe(result => {
    alert(result);
    });
```

**servicio:**

```
delBeneficios(beneficioSelected:community_Beneficios) {
    let headers = new HttpHeaders().append("Accion", "Borrar").set('Content-Type', 'application/json'); 
    return this._http.post(this.url+"Beneficios", {
        beneficioSelected
    }, { headers });
}
```

Desde ya muchas gracias !

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [tour] y, de paso, ganar tu primera medalla. También es importante que leas [ask] y [mcve] para poder mejorar tus preguntas y que sean bien recibidas por la comunidad, de esta manera favoreces a que los usuarios las respondan y te ayuden

Comment: Con [Fiddle](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/how-to-use-fiddler-with-asp-net-web-api-testing/)  realiza una prueba para que primero analises que estas enviando hacia el servidor, tambien si tienes un error en la respuesta.

Comment: Intenta quitando los corchetes que tienes al enviar el objeto despues del parámetro de la url. Dejao asi:  `return this._http.post(this.url+"Beneficios", 
        beneficioSelected, { headers })`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Debes hacer un `map(...)` o un `pipe(map(...))` (según tu versión de angular) en el servicio de http, de esta forma:

```
return this._http.post(this.url+"Beneficios", 
    { beneficioSelected }, 
    { headers }).map((response: any[]) => response);
```